# Why am I getting this error when I try to broadcast to one socket

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

so I have

`socket.endpoint.subscribe("user_socket:" <> socket.id)`

And when I try to broadcast to it

```
      RealmWeb.Endpoint.broadcast(
            "user_socket:#{player_state.socket_id}",
            "quest completed",
            %{})
```

I get this error

```
* (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in RealmWeb.WorldChannel.handle_info/2
(realm 0.1.0) lib/realm_web/channels/world_channel.ex:24: RealmWeb.WorldChannel.handle_info(%Phoenix.Socket.Broadcast{event: "quest completed", payload: %{}, topic: "user_socket:0fef857e-b003-4f86-b571-4a212be9beaa"}, %Phoenix.Socket{assigns: %{}, channel: RealmWeb.WorldChannel, channel_pid: #PID<0.661.0>, endpoint: RealmWeb.Endpoint, handler: RealmWeb.UserSocket, id: "0fef857e-b003-4f86-b571-4a212be9beaa", join_ref: "3", joined: true, private: %{log_handle_in: :debug, log_join: :info}, pubsub_server: Realm.PubSub, ref: nil, serializer: Phoenix.Socket.V2.JSONSerializer, topic: "world:lobby", transport: :websocket, transport_pid: #PID<0.656.0>})
(phoenix 1.6.11) lib/phoenix/channel/server.ex:343: Phoenix.Channel.Server.handle_info/2
(stdlib 3.16.1) gen_server.erl:695: :gen_server.try_dispatch/4
(stdlib 3.16.1) gen_server.erl:771: :gen_server.handle_msg/6
(stdlib 3.16.1) proc_lib.erl:226: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3


Last message: %Phoenix.Socket.Broadcast{event: "quest completed", payload: %{}, topic: "user_socket:0fef857e-b003-4f86-b571-4a212be9beaa"}
State: %Phoenix.Socket{assigns: %{}, channel: RealmWeb.WorldChannel, channel_pid: #PID<0.661.0>, endpoint: RealmWeb.Endpoint, handler: RealmWeb.UserSocket, id: "0fef857e-b003-4f86-b571-4a212be9beaa", join_ref: "3", joined: true, private: %{log_handle_in: :debug, log_join: :info}, pubsub_server: Realm.PubSub, ref: nil, serializer: Phoenix.Socket.V2.JSONSerializer, topic: "world:lobby", transport: :websocket, transport_pid: #PID<0.656.0>}
```

I don't know why this isn't working.

Why is it trying to do a `handle_info` call. I am expecting the code to send a message directly to a specific client.

Comment: Can you please paste the contents of your `RealmWeb.WorldChannel.handle_info/2` function(s) here?

Comment: Also the content of `lib/realm_web/channels/world_channel.ex` around line #24 would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make some assumptions based on the typical implementation of a Phoenix app that are probably correct, but could be different depending on other decisions you've made.

Given the code:

```
socket.endpoint.subscribe("user_socket:" <> socket.id)
```

Assuming the `socket` that is in-scope is a `%Phoenix.Socket{}`, and its endpoint field is set to `RealmWeb.Endpoint`, and assuming `RealmWeb.Endpoint,` implements the behavior `Phoenix.Endpoint`, will subscribe the *current process* to messages on that topic.

Based on the stack trace, it looks like you're subscribing your `Phoenix.Channel` process to these messages. There may be a case for doing that; in our codebase we have a specialized channel that is used by certain clients that happens to be interested in messages from another channel. So we subscribe to those events within the channel within the `OurChannel.join/3` callback, and within that channel module, do something very similar to this:

```
  @impl true
  def handle_info(%{event: event, payload: payload}, socket) do
    push(socket, event, payload)
    {:noreply, socket}
  end
```

Which simply pushes those events to parties interested in them, but subscribed through this channel. We also listen for other types of GenServer-ish events (in our case, a regular check for a particular condition that decides whether the client should stay connected or not, and pushes a phx_close event in appropriate cases.

If subscribing to an external topic is indeed what you're doing, then implementing handle_info in a similar manner is basically all you need to do. See the [Subscribing to external topics](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Channel.html#module-subscribing-to-external-topics) section of the `Phoenix.Channel` docs for more context.

My suspicion, though, is that you meant to have the client `join` the topic rather than have the channel subscribe to an external channel.

If that's the case, then basically you need to have the client do that (more on that in a moment) and then have your channel implement a `join/3` to decide whether it's acceptable for the requesting client to join or not.

The join function could look like something this, if you have an is_authorized/2 function defined:

```
def join("user_socket:" <> socket_id, _payload, socket) do
  if is_authorized?(socket_id, socket) do
    {:ok, socket}
  else
    {:error,  %{reason: "unauthorized"}}
  end
end

def join(_any_channel_without_strict_authorization_rules, _payload, socket) do
  {:ok, socket}
end
```

Then, have your client join the "user_socket:#{user_id}" channel in "the usual way." In the case of LiveView, you can simply subscribe to the channel in your `on_mount` callback; if you're using client-side javascript you can check the [Phoenix js library](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/js/) documentation.